Bolt of rear derailleur rounded out and broke off - repair wire thread
I had an issue with a stuck rear derailleur. The bolt was completely rounded out.
I tried many things:
Heating, penetrating oil and drilling the bolt out with a reverse drill. Eventually when I applied force, the derailleur came off, but part of the bolt is still stuck in the wire thread (a very thin layer of metal). I cannot get it out.
Is there any way to repair this or replace the wire thread? What would you do in my place?
Thanks a lot!
Greetings from a desperate bike enthousiast.



Like so: https://www.sjscycles.co.uk/accessories/dropout-saver-threaded-insert-fits-into-rear-mech-hanger/

Does this work when the thread is in the frame itself? Thanks!

You drill the existing thread out and this replaces it. Other formats exist including inserts that themselves thread into the hole you have drilled and then tapped. Helicoil is also an option although not ideal in this particular application.

This is why one of the reasons frames should have derailleur hangers.

@Noise that's an answer

@Jorun whatever happens, please do keep us updated with your progress.  Your experiences may help future readers.

As @Noise mentioned in the comments, a Dropout Saver or M10x1 spiral-type thread insert (Helicoil) are the main options here.
If you somehow had the ability to get the stuck remnant of pivot bolt out, then you might be able to just put a new RD in, probably after chasing the threads. The problem is that at this point, it's likely never coming out. It's unclear what the pivot bolt material was or what derailleur it was, but the situation suggests it was an aluminum pivot bolt and that it's aluminum-on-aluminum (aluminum oxide) corrosion you're dealing with. Seized, corroded, fine threads between two different aluminum things can be one of the more impossible situations on bikes. All of the remaining things you could try are bad, time-consuming, unlikely to work great, and likely to damage the frame threads anyway.
The Helicoil or Dropout Saver solution lets you drill through, obliterating the stuck pivot bolt and enlarging the main thread. Then you install the insert to get back down to M10. Here you get the extra benefit that it looks like you've cut into the frame outside the threaded hole, and that will mostly be erased too.
As for which of the above, both work very well. I would typically choose a Helicoil type repair for two reasons: the new hole you're drilling is slightly smaller, so more hanger material remains, and occasionally Dropout Savers create chain interference on the small cog, which if it happens requires you thin out the hanger to make room for it. But either is fine.
There's another path on older aluminum bikes with integral hangers like this, which is do surgery so that the dropout just takes a replaceable hanger, like this.

Excellent link to a creative repair

I defer to your practical experience with these repairs, but would a solid-type threaded insert like a Keensert be better than a Helicoil-style spiral insert? I’m not sure how well Helicoils work with fairly thin material (relative to the diameter) like derailleur hangers are. The solid type might be more resistant to coming loose considering the little locking pins?

@MaplePanda good idea - it could depend how much metal is left after the hole is drilled.  It may be better for OP to cut off this whole hanger and re-create it from fresh metal though that would require machine-shop skills, and would probably be cost-prohibitive.

@MaplePanda Full disclosure I haven't used any any of the solid wall type like Keensert, Timesert, etc. That said, when I've looked at the drill size and tap major diameter charts for the different options you can get for M10x1, Helicoil always seems to need the smallest hole/have the smallest major diameter for the tap, and that's really the deciding factor among the choices because all of them eat more of the parent material than you'd like, especially on steel bikes. Helicoil is very resistant to the insert coming out when you install the insert dry and grease whatever is going into it.

The other thing as a practical matter is that despite this entire kind of repair seeming a little advanced/intimidating, Helicoil is fast, easy to trim to the exact final thickness you want, the inserts themselves are inexpensive, and there are other things on bikes that sometimes need M10x1 Helicoils (Lefties use them for the hub attachment bolt and I've fixed a couple of those that came out, which is horrifying, but it's a thing).

Additional ideas, should the hanger repair not work but you still want to save the frame:
An Internally Geared Hub will allow you gearing without requiring the mount hole for the RD.  Downside, they're a little heavier and you won't be able to use any front derailleur. On the upside, you can change gears while completely stopped.
A single-speed or fixed gear conversion might suit your needs too, however that means no ability to select a gear.
